# I have problem with sort the matrix. [MergeSort]

Tags: java, sorting, matrix, merge

Displays the list of matrix columns on the screen, in descending order of the maximum in the respective columns; data sorting will be done through merge sort.
I write the maximal elements in the vector, then the vector is sorted, and already from the vector you have to display the columns. And if there are 2 identical numbers in the matrix, it has to display the correct column, it must work with coordinates, but I failed.

```
2  6  1 
10  5  11 
4  8  9
```

Final result

```
1  2  6 
11  10  5 
9  4  8
```

```
static void maxVec(int[][] myArray, int n, int m) {
        int[] elMax=new int[m];
        for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
            int max=0;
            if(n>m) {
                int count=(n-m);
                for (int j=0; j<myArray[i].length+count; j++) {
                    if(myArray[j][i]>max) {
                        max=myArray[j][i];
                    }
                }
            }
            if(n==m) {
                for (int j=0; j<myArray[i].length; j++) {
                    if(myArray[j][i]>max) {
                        max=myArray[j][i];
                    }
                }
            }
            if(n<m) {
                int count=(m-n);
                for (int j=0; j<m-count; j++) {
                    if(myArray[j][i]>max) {
                        max=myArray[j][i];
                    }
                }
            }
            elMax[i]=max;
        }
        mergeSort(elMax, elMax.length);
        for(int i=0;i<elMax.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(elMax[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n===================================");
//here i don't know what to do
        for(int k=0;k<elMax.length;k++) {
            for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<myArray[i].length; j++) {
                    if(elMax[k]==myArray[i][j]) {
                            for (int w=0; w<myArray[w].length; w++) {
                                System.out.print(myArray[i][w]+" ");
                            }
                            System.out.println();


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //merge sort



    public static void merge(
              int[] a, int[] l, int[] r, int left, int right) {

                int i=0, j=0, k=0;
                while(i<left && j<right) {
                    if(l[i]>=r[j]) {
                        a[k++]=l[i++];
                    }
                    else {
                        a[k++]=r[j++];
                    }
                }
                while(i<left) {
                    a[k++]=l[i++];

                }
                while(j<right) {
                    a[k++]=r[j++];
                }
            }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] a, int n) {
        if(n<2) {
            return;
        }
        int mid =n/2;
        int[] l = new int[mid];
        int[] r = new int[n-mid];

        for(int i=0;i<mid;i++) {
            l[i]=a[i];
        }
        for(int i=mid;i<n;i++) {
            r[i-mid]=a[i];
        }
        mergeSort(l, mid);
        mergeSort(r, n-mid);

        merge(a, l, r, mid, n-mid);
    }
```

Comment: The basic problem is that you are sorting an array of maximum values instead of sorting what you want to sort, which is the matrix. Rewrite your mergeSort routine so that it sorts the matrix, that's the most straightforward way to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps you, and better use this on not very large matrix,

```
class Matrix {

    int[][] matrix = new int[][] {
        { 1,  3,  5, 16,  9},
        { 2,  4, 15,  6,  0},
        {18, 14, 17, 11, 10},
        {14, 15, 12, 16, 13}
    };

    void sortByColumn() {

        class ColMax {
            int col;
            int val;

            ColMax(int c, int v) {
                col = c;
                val = v;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "[" + col + ": " + val + "]";
            }
        }

        int cols = matrix[0].length;
        int rows = matrix.length;
        int[][] target = new int[rows][cols];
        ColMax[] colmaxes = new ColMax[cols];

        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            colmaxes[i] = new ColMax(i, matrix[0][i]);
        }

        // find every column's max item  
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++) {
                if (colmaxes[i].val < matrix[k][i]) {
                    colmaxes[i].val = matrix[k][i];
                }
            }
        }

        // sort it descending
        Arrays.sort(colmaxes, (a,b) -> b.val - a.val);

        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i ++) {
            System.out.print(colmaxes[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        // copy sorted cols 
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
                target[i][k] = matrix[i][colmaxes[k].col];
                System.out.print(target[i][k] + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a good method, but you didn't use Merge Sort. Here it's possible to use it?

Comment: Yes, I have to show my teacher how to implement Merge Sort. I didn't know that Arrays.sort uses merge sorting. How can I explain that or please show me how I can implement merge sort (Sorry for my english)

Comment: I got it, allright then, good luck. I have just show one of the way that can achieve this.  and just a little bit googling you can find an implementation of merge sort.

Comment: My bad, Arrays.sort uses DualPivotQuickSort, not merge.